# Linq thenby running indefinitely

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function that is simply meant to print out a dictionary of frequent item sets in an easy-to-understand fashion.  The goal is to order first by the size of the dictionary key and then by the lexicographical order of a list of numbers.  The issue arises in the ThenBy statement as the commented out "hello" will get printed indefinitely.  If I change the ThenBy to not use the comparer and simply use another int or string value, it works fine, so I'm clearly doing something wrong.

```
public static void printItemSets(Dictionary<List<int>, int> freqItemSet)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<List<int>, int>> printList = freqItemSet.ToList();
    printList = printList.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Count)
                         .ThenBy(x => x.Key, new ListComparer())
                         .ToList();
}
```

The code for the ListComparer is as follows:

```
public class ListComparer: IEqualityComparer<List<int>>, IComparer<List<int>>
{
    public int Compare(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        int larger = a.Count > b.Count ? 1: -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count && i < b.Count; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < b[i])
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a[i] > b[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else { }
        }
        return larger;
    }
}
```

VERY simple test case:

```
int[] a = {1, 3, 5};
int[] b = { 2, 3, 5 };
int[] c = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
int[] d = { 2, 5 };
int[] e = { 1, 3, 4 };
List<int> aL = a.ToList<int>();
List<int> bL = b.ToList<int>();
List<int> cL = c.ToList<int>();
List<int> dL = d.ToList<int>();
List<int> eL = e.ToList<int>();
Dictionary<List<int>, int> test = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>(new ListComparer());
test.Add(aL, 1);
test.Add(bL, 1);
test.Add(cL, 1);
test.Add(dL, 1);
test.Add(eL, 1);
```

Comment: Looks like it should terminate eventually. It does seem like it has the likelihood to be especially slow, though. Have you tried running this as a unit test? Have you tried using a mock dictionary with only a few elements to make sure the code does as intended?

Comment: I'm currently testing it with a dictionary of only 4 items, so, that should be sufficiently small.  As its just a print function and I'm not expecting exceptionally large lists, it may still be ok.  I'm mostly in 'draft' mode and am just trying to write up something that will work correctly.

Comment: Your comparer doesn't handle equal items.  If the items are equal the order of the two items is what determines which is considered "larger".  The comparer is thus not "reflexive".  This is a property sorting algorithms rely on.  The first line should be `var larger = a.Count.CompareTo(b.Count);` instead.  That said, it wouldn't cause the problem that you're seeing.

Comment: How is the dictionary populated?  Show the code for that.  My guess is that you have a bunch of references to the same list which you're mutating over and over, when you should have multiple references to different lists.

Comment: Because the items are coming from a dictionary, its not possible for there to be two lists that are equal.  Nevertheless, I can put that check into the compare function.

Comment: @DanielCappuccio The list can be equal if the equality semantics are different, which they very well can be.  There is no assurance that the dictionary is using the same equality comparer as your method is.  In fact, sorting is going to use an `IComparer` while a `Dictionary` is going to use `IEqualityComparer`.  Having different methods, they're going to be implemented differently.  You cannot be using that single method for both.

Comment: Also, how are you printing the results and getting "hello"?

Comment: Because `=` is never handled, won't `ThenBy` continue to loop indefinitely trying to sort to get everything to be in the order of `-1, 0, 1` for ascending? Everything will always come back to -1 or 1 and continue to compare different items possibly never getting the correct order to stop the compare. Am I right?

Comment: @TyCobb While that is theoretically possible (because anything is possible when you don't meet the contract given for the method) that won't actually happen.  And in this specific example there are no equal lists, so while that should indeed be fixed, it's not the cause of this particular problem.

Comment: @Servy I just ran the code and breakpointed after a few seconds. My theory is slightly correct. It's blowing up because `=` is not being handled due to it being passed in the same array twice. In this case, the array of `{2, 5}` is getting passed in as both `x` and `y` after n number of iterations.

Comment: So why is {2, 5} getting passed in both times?  I'll implement the equals clause and meet the contract and perhaps see what happens.  I originally had a Console.WriteLine("hello") as the first line of the compare method, but someone edited it out.

Comment: AAAANNND it's fixed.  simply added if(a == b) return 0 to the start of the compare method and it sorts correctly!  Thank you all for pointing that out.

Comment: And not to rub it in Daniel, but 30 seconds of debugging and putting in a breakpoint easily showed the issue. Please put some effort into debugging issues. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: I had tried the break point in the compare function, but, honestly I had not considered the breach of contract until it was mentioned.  Once TyCobb mentioned 2,5 getting passed in both times a light went off.  You can run things through the debugger, but if you're overlooking a relatively simple issue, you may not be looking in the right place.  Thus was the case here.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @DanielCappuccio adding `if(a == b) return 0;` does *not* resolve the issue in the general case.  If two lists are provided that really are different lists, but that have the same items, they will cause this exact same problem.  See my first comment for a proper solution that will work in *all* cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `ListComparer` is not checking if the arrays are the same. The same array is being passed in twice for both `x` and `y`. Checking if `x` and `y` are equal will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparer doesn't handle equal items. If the items are equal the order of the two items is what determines which is considered "larger". The comparer is thus not "reflexive". Being reflexive is a property sorting algorithms rely on.

The first line should be `var larger = a.Count.CompareTo(b.Count);` instead, so that truly equal lists will return `0` rather than either `-1` or `1`.